# Is it possible to index a table in Angularjs with dates?

Tags: angularjs, indexing

I am working on creating a graph depending on the date with two series :

- number of items created
- number of items updated

I made a request from our API and got a file which has the following datas :

```
"result":[
{
"closed_on" : "YYYY-MM-DD",
"created_on" : "YYYY-MM-DD"
}
{
"closed_on" : "YYYY-MM-DD",
"created_on" : "YYYY-MM-DD"
}
{
"closed_on" : "YYYY-MM-DD",
"created_on" : "YYYY-MM-DD"
}
{...}
]
```

I was wondering what was the best solution to get the data for the graph as a collection of objects of this type  :

```
x : date,
created : integer,
updated : integer
```

I thought it was to have a table with the date as an index and go over the whole file and increment the value in the indexed table.

However, I had some issues finding info on Internet.
I thought about something like that :

```
  $scope.datas=[];

  $scope.date = $scope.date.start;

  while($scope.date!==$scope.date.end) 
  {
      $scope.datas.push({
      date
      : [{
        closed_tickets:0,
        created_tickets:0
      }]
    });

      $scope.date = $scope.date.addDays(1);


  }
```

However, it doesn't work.. Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) . Something like this:

```
$scope.dateList = response.result //get the array of dates

$scope.datas = $scope.dateList.reduce(function(prev, current, index, array) {
 var closedIndex = prev.findIndex(function(ele, i, a) {ele.x == current.closed_on}); 
 if(closedIndex > -1) 
   prev[closedIndex].closed_tickets++;
 else
   prev.push({x:current.closed_on, closed_tickets:1, created_tickets:0});

 var createdIndex = prev.findIndex(function(ele, i, a) {ele.x == current.created_on}); 
 if(createdIndex > -1) 
   prev[createdIndex ].created_tickets++;
 else
   prev.push({x:current.created_on, closed_tickets:0, created_tickets:1});

 return prev;

}, []);
```